Automatically adding hyperlinks in footnotes in MS Word
The below vba code for MS Word (described here: text works very well for converting urls added to XE codes in Word to hyperlinks.  However it does not work in footnotes.  Does anyone know how to edit the visual basic code so it will do this?
Thanks
Sub MakeConcordance() '

Const hBase As String = "../Text/"
Const htm As String = ".htm"
Dim aCell As Cell
Dim aString As String

For Each aCell In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2).Cells
    aString = hBase & Trim(Left$(aCell.Range.Text, (Len(aCell.Range.Text) - 2))) & htm
    aCell.Range.Text = aString
Next aCell

End Sub

Sub MakeHyperlinks()
Dim afield As Field
Dim url As String
Dim isHyper As Integer

For Each afield In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If afield.Type = wdFieldIndexEntry Then
        isHyper = 0
        afield.Select
        Selection.Collapse
        url = Right$(afield.Code, Len(afield.Code) - 5)
        url = Left$(url, Len(url) - 2)

        If Left$(url, 4) = "../F" Then
            isHyper = 1
        End If

        If Left$(url, 4) = "../T" Then
            isHyper = 2
        End If

        If isHyper <> 0 Then
             Selection.MoveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-3
             Selection.MoveStart unit:=wdWord, Count:=-isHyper
             afield.Delete
             ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
               Address:=url
        End If
    End If

Next afield

End Sub

XE codes can be added in MS Word with the AutoMark tool under References . . . Insert Index, but I don't see how to convert those codes to hyperlinks unless I strip out the footnotes to end notes - but then it's too difficult to convert the end notes back to footnotes.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

The Automark indexing feature should create the XE fields you need in the footnotes. The problem is that the loop processing the fields only processes the fields in the main body of the document. The fields in the Footnote are in another "StoryRange". You can process the fields in all possible storyranges using the code at e.g. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm and modifying your For Each loop as appropriate.

Like @jonsson said use StoryRange object plz, like this, you can try first:
Sub MakeHyperlinks()
Dim afield As Field
Dim url As String
Dim isHyper As Integer

Dim sr As Range

For Each sr In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'For Each afield In ActiveDocument.Fields
    For Each afield In sr.Fields
        If afield.Type = wdFieldIndexEntry Then
            isHyper = 0
            afield.Select
            Selection.Collapse
            url = Right$(afield.Code, Len(afield.Code) - 5)
            url = Left$(url, Len(url) - 2)
    
            If Left$(url, 4) = "../F" Then
                isHyper = 1
            End If
    
            If Left$(url, 4) = "../T" Then
                isHyper = 2
            End If
    
            If isHyper <> 0 Then
                 Selection.MoveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-3
                 Selection.MoveStart unit:=wdWord, Count:=-isHyper
                 afield.Delete
                 ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
                   Address:=url
            End If
        End If
    
    Next afield
Next sr
End Sub


Super!  This works perfectly.  It adds the hyperlinks in both the body and the footnotes at the same time.  I am very grateful, Oscar.  I often have to review documents with hundreds of footnotes and this will save me a lot of time.  I will give you a shout out on my blog:  https://www.litigationsupporttipofthenight.com/

Btw, I tried many times to get ChatGPT to update this vba code for me, and it always failed to give me something that worked.  So, Oscar, you are still better than AI at vba.

@SeanO-LitSupTipofNite : Glad to be of help. In that case, please accept this answer to close this question. Thanks a lot.
